# Neural Net - trying to predict that 5 + 5 = 10

Tags: machine-learning, python

I'm learning about Neural Networks and I recently had this idea: trying to give a NN training data of the function $f(x) = 2x$. The question is, can the NN accurately predict that it has to double the input number to give the correct output?

This is just a "mental exercise", to better my understanding of how NNs work.

My Python code doesn't work, here's what I've tried:

Neural Network class:

```
import numpy as np

class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self, inputnodes, hiddennodes, outputnodes, learningrate):
        self.inodes = inputnodes
        self.hnodes = hiddennodes
        self.onodes = outputnodes

        self.lr = learningrate

        self.wih = np.random.normal(0.0, pow(self.inodes, -0.5), (self.hnodes, self.inodes))
        self.who = np.random.normal(0.0, pow(self.hnodes, -0.5), (self.onodes, self.hnodes))

    def train(self, inputs_list, targets_list):
        inputs = np.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T
        targets = np.array(targets_list, ndmin=2).T

        hidden_outputs = np.dot(self.wih, inputs)
        final_outputs = np.dot(self.who, hidden_outputs)

        output_errors = targets - final_outputs
        hidden_errors = np.dot(self.who.T, output_errors)

        self.who += self.lr * np.dot(
            (output_errors * final_outputs * (1.0 - final_outputs)),
            np.transpose(hidden_outputs)
        )

        self.wih += self.lr * np.dot(
            (hidden_errors * hidden_outputs * (1.0 - hidden_outputs)),
            np.transpose(inputs)
        )

    def query(self, inputs_list):
        inputs = np.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T
        hidden_outputs = np.dot(self.wih, inputs)
        final_outputs = np.dot(self.who, hidden_outputs)

        return final_outputs
```

Training the network and predicting a value:

```
input_nodes = 1
hidden_nodes = 20
output_nodes = 1

learning_rate = 0.3

nn = NeuralNetwork(input_nodes, hidden_nodes, output_nodes, learning_rate)

for i in range(10):
    i += 1
    inputs = np.log(i)
    targets = np.log(2*i)
    nn.train(inputs, targets)

print(nn.query(np.asfarray([4])))
```

Here's the output I'm getting trying to run this code:

```
x.py:26: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply
  (output_errors * final_outputs * (1.0 - final_outputs)),  
x.py:31: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply
  (hidden_errors * hidden_outputs * (1.0 - hidden_outputs)),  
[[nan]]
```

I don't really know how to interpret this, and if my design is correct for this application. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Since the function of interest (`f(x)=2x`) is linear and requires only one weight, we can vastly simplify the network by having 1 weight and 0 hidden layers.  We're trying to debug a problem, so we should simplify as much as possible to eliminate sources of error.  Using a hidden layer with multiple hidden nodes implies that we need to find matrices such that `W1.dot(W2)=2` because we seek the function `x.dot(W1).dot(W2)`, which is harder because changing 1 weight changes the entire product; finding the correct answer requires aligning all of those weights.
- Because the function of interest is linear, we know that any use of nonlinear functions is a distraction. Also, Saturation of sigmoid and tanh functions, or the dying ReLU phenomenon, could introduce additional problems to the optimization dynamics which could prevent us from making progress. See: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/301285/what-is-vanishing-gradient
- The learning rate is probably too large. I believe this is the problem because you're having numerical overflow; this can happen when the optimizer consistently overshoots the minimum. See: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/364360/how-can-change-in-cost-function-be-positive
- Scaling the inputs and the targets of a regression problem can dramatically improve the optimizer dynamics. For an example, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/432707/alternating-negative-and-positive-value-of-slope-and-y-intercept-in-gradient-des/432714#432714
- Additional tips for training neural networks are here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/352036/what-should-i-do-when-my-neural-network-doesnt-learn/352037#352037

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for the thorough answer !! I implemented a super simple perceptron with no bias and it works.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are missing a very important part / building block in artificial neural networks architecture , this block is called the activation function , which tries to normalize output between [0,1] or [-1,1]
so i think attaching (which is very important) an activation function after computing every hidden layer outputs may solve this problem , as data propagating network will maintain normalized values for example between [0,1] so overflow may will not happen

notes

1. sigmoid activation and tanh are most popular and suitable for you problem
2. your learning rate maybe slightly large , try use 0.01

Comment: This network is attempting to solve a linear problem, so the addition of nonlinear activations is a distraction. A "degenerate" neural network with only linear activations and no hidden layers (otherwise known as a **linear regression**) can solve this problem.

Comment: This is the part I don't understand. Initially, I tried with sigmoid activation functions, but my output was... between 0 and 1. Which is a problem, because if my input is greater than 1, I won't get the correct output. For ex if I input 6, I want 12 and not something between 0 and 1.

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica interesting, so from what I understand you think that I should try with ReLU and no hidden layer? Can it still work with a hidden layer?

Comment: No, any activation function is unnecessary because f(x) = 2x is a linear function. The problem you're facing is numerical and related to the choices of how you carry out backpropagation. I haven't made a careful study of the code, but the numerical overflow is occurring because some values are growing without bound. The first place I would look is the learning rate.

Comment: @RotirNoir normalizing data still reflects its weights , for example if you have a list of numbers between [1,100] normalized version may map 1 to be 0.0 and 100 to be 0.99 so large still large and min still min , it is just a transformation , unormalized data will accumulate in every iteration and will end in to overflow problem

Comment: you also may use relu activation

Comment: Activation unfctions introduce non-linearities in your network - they don't necessarily normalize the feature.